# How to update Xamarin for Android within Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

I've recently installed Visual Studio Community 2015 and I've been following an MSDN tutorial ["Build cross-platform apps with Xamarin"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn879698%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). When its time to design the look of the app and I select the Main.axml file in the Resources\layout folder, the Android designer fails with:

**The installed Android SDK is too old. Version 24.3.4 or newer is required. Please update to the latest version.**

I've done a lot of searching and found that one of the newer versions of Android SDK caused the Xamarin Android designer to fail. I did find a version 24.4.1 that suggests this designer problem is fixed.

How do I update this part of Visual Studio (i.e. Xamarin.Android)? Here is a snippet of my install on Windows 7:
[image]

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Tools --> Options --> Xamarin

Under "iOS Settings" and "Android Settings" there is a link for "Check Now" next to the Updates settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This fires up a wizard and shuts down Visual Studio and eventually everything gets updated. I restarted VS and the Android designer is now properly initiallized when I select Main.axml. This is definitely not "our father's Visual Studio" anymore!

Comment: In recent version there is "Other" node under Xamarin option. Click on Other node to check for updates.

Comment: This worked for me when auto updates continuously failed. Ended up with about 4 xamarin update icons in taskbar.

Comment: I found that this made it even worse - now its demanding Android SDK v25.1.3 or later !  Android Studio continues to run fine, and Android SDK Manager only knows about Android SDKs upto v24.  This wouldn't be so bad, but I just want to knock up my first dumb basic Android app... and Xamarin won't let me !!

Comment: This is no longer there in VS 2017 ??

Answer (score 11):

You might want to update to Beta release if you need the latest components -

Goto VS 2015 -> Tools -> Option -> Xamarin -> Others -> Check Now

[image]

Answer (score 8):

They moved the "Check Now" into the harder-to-find `Tools/Options/Xamarin/Other`.  We must always be on guard when dealing with the

> Other

[image: Watch for the exciting new location]

Comment: VS 2017 (Community, at least) doesn't have it there.

Answer (score 4):

In newer Version of Visual studio this option is available in `Other` node

Goto VS 2015 -> Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other -> Check Now

[image]

Here you can choose between **Alpha, Beta or Stable** versions of `xamarin for Visual Studio`.

Comment: They moved the "Check Now".  Harder to find.  Must click "Other" on the "Xamarin" tree in Options

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, my problem was solved after installing SDK Platform for Android 6.0 or API 23. API 24 or higher i.e Android 7.0 (Nougat) didnt run. If still not solved then install SDK Platform for even lower APIs like 22,21 ...
Hope it helps.