# Unable to run Xamarin Android project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

While trying to create and run the first Xamarin app with all the defaults, the build fails with the following error:

```
An unexpected error occurred trying to initialize Android Designer. 
Please verify the Android SDK path and the Java Development Kit path on 
Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu. Please see the logs for more details.
```

I tried the solution suggested in [How to resolve : unexpected error occured Initializing Android Designer" in VS 2015 with Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548053/how-to-resolve-unexpected-error-occured-initializing-android-designer-in-vs-2). 
However, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Any solution for this? I am not able to build any Android project, it throws errors at styles.xml.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548053/how-to-resolve-unexpected-error-occured-initializing-android-designer-in-vs-2

Comment: For some reason I had to re-install Visual Studio (update 3). During the installation, I selected the necessary components for Xamarin. However, I'm still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I have [followed the link that you shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39680307/3424212) and successfully solved my environment. So I'll give some hints to make sure that all the necessary steps were made.

I was having the same error "An unexpected error occurred trying to initialize Android Designer. Please verify the Android SDK path and the  Java Development Kit path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu. Please see the logs for more details."

> 1) Go to Tools | Options | Xamarin | Other, and under Xamarin for
>   Visual Studio Updates, Check now for STABLE updates. Make sure you're
>   running at least 4.2.0.680. You will have to close Visual Studio in
>   the background as the updater is running--it'll warn you. Uninstalling
>   and installing the cross-platform development tools from Visual Studio
>   was not applying this update for me. I had to force the issue.

To check Xamarion Version, you can follow the steps in the "Version information" section:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/

[image]

If you are using Windows and Visual Studio it will be :
Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio > Copy Info [button]

> 2) Now, as mentioned earlier, go to Tools, Android SDK Manager. I
>   noticed my "Android SDK Tools" and "Cross Platform Tools" were out of
>   date and updates were available. I accepted and applied the updates to
>   version 24.4.1. BEAR WITH ME, THIS IS WHERE IT GETS TRICKY--it still
>   didn't work.

To check Android SDK Version, You can follow the steps in the "Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, Build-tools" section:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/

If you are using Windows and Visual Studio it will be :
Select the SDK Manager toolbar icon:
[image]

3) It is important to repeat step 2, updating "Android SDK Tools" until you go at least version 25.2.5

[image]

After that all have worked for me. Please let me know if you have any further problem.

Comment: I did work for me too. Thanks a lot. Much appreciated. :) However, I'm unable to deploy the app on Xamarin Android Player emulator. I hope you have a solution for that as well.